# Added item to a list but it will not sort alphabetically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

The below code is used to create a dropdown list of services that my company offers. The services are being pulled from our database and I hard coded and added an additional item named "SSN Trace" to the list. The problem is that the item is still showing up at the end of the list instead of falling in alphabetical order with the rest of the list items. Can anyone help?

```
public List<SelectListItem> createProductsDropdownForTransReport()
        {
            var resultsOfProductsSearch = findAllByEnumSet(EnumLookup.EnumSetType.SterlingWestProducts);

            var transanctionsReportProducts = resultsOfProductsSearch
                .Where(el => el.Ordinal != 95 && el.Ordinal != 253)
                .Select(el => new SelectListItem { Text = el.Text, Value = el.Text })
                .OrderBy(el => el.Text)
                .ToList();

            transanctionsReportProducts.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "SSN Trace", Value = "SSN Trace" }); 

            var allTransReportProductsOption = new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "All",
                Value = String.Join(" | ", transanctionsReportProducts.Select(x => x.Text)) 
        };

            transanctionsReportProducts.Insert(0, allTransReportProductsOption);

            transanctionsReportProducts.OrderBy(el => el.Text);

            return transanctionsReportProducts;
        }
```

**CORRECT CODE:**

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> createProductsDropdownForTransReport()
        {
            var resultsOfProductsSearch = findAllByEnumSet(EnumLookup.EnumSetType.SterlingWestProducts);

            var transanctionsReportProducts = resultsOfProductsSearch
                .Where(el => el.Ordinal != 95 && el.Ordinal != 253)
                .Select(el => new SelectListItem { Text = el.Text, Value = el.Text }).ToList();



            transanctionsReportProducts.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "SSN Trace", Value = "SSN Trace" });

            transanctionsReportProducts = transanctionsReportProducts.OrderBy(el => el.Text).ToList();

            var allTransReportProductsOption = new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "All",
                Value = String.Join(" | ", transanctionsReportProducts.Select(x => x.Text)) 
        };

            transanctionsReportProducts.Insert(0, allTransReportProductsOption);

            return transanctionsReportProducts;
        }
```

Comment: may be try this? `transanctionsReportProducts = transanctionsReportProducts.OrderBy(el => el.Text);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not doing anything on the return by `OrderBy`. You can immediately return the result of the `OrderBy`. When you call `OrderBy`, it doesn't mutate the existing list that you passed in. It creates a new list of the ordered elements and you are not doing anything on it.

More information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> createProductsDropdownForTransReport()
{
    var resultsOfProductsSearch = findAllByEnumSet(
        EnumLookup.EnumSetType.SterlingWestProducts);

    var transanctionsReportProducts = resultsOfProductsSearch
        .Where(el => el.Ordinal != 95 && el.Ordinal != 253)
        .Select(el => new SelectListItem { Text = el.Text, Value = el.Text })
        .OrderBy(el => el.Text)
        .ToList();

    transanctionsReportProducts.Add(new SelectListItem { 
        Text = "SSN Trace", Value = "SSN Trace" }); 

    var allTransReportProductsOption = new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "All",
        Value = String.Join(" | ", transanctionsReportProducts.Select(x => x.Text)) 
    };

    transanctionsReportProducts.Insert(0, allTransReportProductsOption);

    return transanctionsReportProducts.OrderBy(el => el.Text);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying change my return statement to reflect your code snippet?

Comment: Remove your  existing return and add return when you do OrderBy

Comment: Good catch. BTW I think you'll also want to do a ToList() call on it.

Comment: @EJoshuaS No he does not. As much as possible return `IEnumerable<T>`. Let the caller do the `ToList` if necessary.

Comment: @lll fair point - not sure I agree but you could definitely make a case for that.

Comment: I edited original post with your proposed change but I am getting an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert type.. 'Linq.IOrderedEnumberable'... to 'Collections.Generic.List '. Any idea?

Comment: @DeanFriedland You need to change your return type to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. If you want it to be `List` then you need to do `ToList()` at the end.

Comment: I tried that as well and got an error:  "Cannot convert method group "ToList" to non-delegate type 'List<SelectListItem>'."

Comment: @DeanFriedland I updated my answer to reflect what you need to paste.

Comment: It is throwing an error on another method being used by method, regarding the type being implementer. I have to leave the office so I will have to toy around with it this evening. I really appreciate the help as this is my first dev role and I have been struggling on the issue all day. I will update you later this evening.

Comment: @lll I edited my OP with the controller method issue that I am having when I change the type from List to IEnumerable. Do you know how I can explicitly convert this method in my controller? I tried adding ToList to to the end like:  clientReportService.GetAllTransReportProducts().ToList but it did not like that

Comment: I'm an idiot! No parens after my ToList.... :( It's working now but I did have to change my code a bit and i will add it to the OP so you can see it.

Comment: One question though... Why did changing the type to IEnumerable from List allow it to work correctly???

Comment: Anyone have an idea?